# Considerations for developing a large scale system that needs to be both traditional web accessible and mobile accessible

Tags: web-applications, development-process, mobile

I am trying to begin planning of a system that would be both client management, and document management, with tools built in to do analysis on all of the transactions, etc.

I'm wondering what are the considerations I need to be mindful of at the beginning stages so that when I need to scale up I haven't shot myself in the foot in the beginning.

I also need to make sure that it is mobile accessible and not just traditional web accessible.

I've never done a large scale system like this and I have ample time to plan so any suggestions are much appreciated.

**Edit**

I also need to make sure that the handling of data would be secure because it would be sensitive client data.

Comment: it would help if you specified the programming language that you want to use (e.g. java, c#, php, etc.)

Comment: @linkerro I don't really know, and am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Rather than building something from the gound up, have you researched any existing ECM software? Just curious.

Comment: @mkulesz no I have not considered ECM software. Do you have a suggestion or further comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think of at least three distinct systems in the beginning.

1. Backend/API
2. Web interface
3. Mobile Application

And, later on think of an additional system

A. You need to build the Backend/Server/API such that it is only concerned with data. Read about [REST based APIs](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284) to start with. This API should most preferably *receive* and *return* data in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). The benefit of building the system like this is that view(s) are very clearly separated from data.

B. You can work on 2 & 3 in parallel. You can use javascript mvc framework for Web. Also, read a bit about the [MVVM design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel).

Answer (score 1):

There are several frameworks that may provide this flexibility, and one of them is ASP.NET MVC latest version. This framework creates a mobile ready MVC 3.0 project using the Razor's view engine and jQuery mobile. Both **mobile and desktop versions** can be tested using mobile emulators or browsers.

More information for reference:

- [Mobile Ready HTML5 MVC.NET](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9df9c61c-4d90-43e5-9aa1-a58786b7a1e4)
- [ASP.NET MVC 4 - Default template changes and Adaptive Rendering using Viewport and CSS Media Queries](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/10/06/asp-net-mvc-4-overview-part-2-default-template-changes-and-adaptive-rendering.aspx)
- [Mobile Support in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mobile)